# Can't scrape search results, google keep changing html structure

Tags: php, web-scraping, google-search

My goal is to scrape search results with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser
which is working fine for me. But after every one or two days, Google changes their HTML structure and my code stop working.

Here's my code that was working before:

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow');
$html = str_get_html($data);
$i=0;
$linkObjs = $html->find('h3[class=r] a');
foreach ($linkObjs as $linkObj) {
    $i++;
    $url = trim($linkObj->href);
    $trim = substr($url, 0, 7);
    if ($trim=="/url?q=") {
        $url = substr($url, 7);
    }
    $trim_2 = stripos($url, '&amp;sa=U');
    if ($trim_2 != false) {
        $url = substr($url, 0, $trim_2);
    }
    echo "$i:".$url.'<br>';
}
```

They usually change class names and tag name along with HTML links structure

Comment: and that is why its changing. because you guys want to scrape it. you can just use api yo know, you can force your way into scraping the normal page ones, but you'll get blocked eventually

Comment: I said use their API. I'm having trouble actually finding one for general web search.

Comment: This scraping would be part of SERP position tracker and we can't get accurate position with API

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Try

```
$linkObjs = $html->find('div[class=jfp3ef] a');
```

and it will work again.

Comment: Thanks, it's working but also grabbing links from the featured snippet of the same site. Which is causing wrong SERP position. 
P.S Sorry for late reply

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar experience. When I search Google from the ordinary user interface, the URLs of the "hit" pages are still showing up in an A tag (of course) after a div class 'r'. But when I run my scraping program with the exact same search terms and parameters, the 'r' changes to 'kCrYT'. I changed that in my code and got the program working again. (Yay!)

But I suspect the class will change regularly when Google detects that someone is submitting the search programmatically. So this might not be a permanent solution.

Maybe I could add a little extra code that determines what class name is currently being used for this, so that my program could automatically adapt to these changes.

Comment: Parsing the page should not be a solution, using the API is the normal way - https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Comment: Update: I decided to forget about whatever the class is called and search instead for the string /url?q= at the beginning of the href value. This string /url?q= precedes all of the URLs that represent search hits. Hopefully this will make my program impervious to random changes in that class name.